# Sharepoint Online Search on Enterprise Keywords

Tags: sharepoint

I have added an enterprise keywords column to my document library and added a custom tag of 'RandomDocTag' to a document.

I assumed, that this would be indexed by the search engine and initially assumed that I found nothing by searching for 'RandomDocTag' because the crawl had not yet happened.

It is now more than 3 days since I set that value and I still get no results when using search.

Any ideas? Do I need to set something for this column to be included in the search index?

Comment: Have you reset the search index? Are they showing up as crawled properties?

Comment: Well I cant find it in the managed properties in the search schema so I guess that's what is going wrong. Is it not there by default or has someone removed it?